# How to seed data to a List<String> model member?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an Asp.Net MVC project up and running and I'm able to seed all the data I want to the database when my model changes except for one property which is of `List<string>` type.

I've isolated that test case to better show the issue.

Lets's say I've a simple `Person` model:

```
class Person
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public List<string> Children { get; set; }

    public string ToString()
    {
        string children = "";

        if (Children != null)
        {
            children = String.Join(" - ", Children.ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            children = "none";
        }

        return Firstname + " " + Lastname + " -> " + children;
    }
}
```

When I use this model in an external Console application, I'm able to initialize all of its member.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> myList = new List<Person> {
            new Person { Firstname = "John", Lastname = "Doe", Children = new List<string> { "Bob", "Monica" }},
            new Person { Firstname = "Bob", Lastname = "Doe", Children = new List<string> { "Jack", "John II" }},
            new Person { Firstname = "Monica", Lastname = "Doe", Children = new List<string> { "Sue", "Mark" }}
        };

        // output the list to screen
        myList.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.ToString()));
    }
}
```

The output is then as expected:

```
John Doe -> Bob - Monica
Bob Doe -> Jack - John II
Monica Doe -> Sue - Mark
```

But now when I try to seed the same data into my database, the `Children` member is `null` !

Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
public class MySeedData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDataBaseContextClass>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDataBaseContextClass context)
    {
        List<Person> myList = new List<Person> {
            new Person { Firstname = "John", Lastname = "Doe", Children = new List<string> { "Bob", "Monica" }},
            new Person { Firstname = "Bob", Lastname = "Doe", Children = new List<string> { "Jack", "John II" }},
            new Person { Firstname = "Monica", Lastname = "Doe", Children = new List<string> { "Sue", "Mark" }}
        };
        myList.ForEach(p => context.Persons.Add(p));
    }
}
```

I've tried a lot of different construction patterns but every time the `Children` member is `null` whenever I try to access it in one of my Views.

At the moment, the only way I've found to have this member being not null is to initialize the list in the default constructor of the `Person` class...

So how can I seed data to this `Children` member with different values for each person?

Comment: There's no need to create an array with `ToArray` in `String.Join(" - ", Children.ToArray())` if you use .NET 4. Are you using at least .NET 4?

Comment: Thinking database : how the hell would a `List<string>` be stored in a database ???

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for the info, I didn't notice that now I can do that. I'm using .NET 4.5 for this project but used to use 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that EF doesn't support collections of scalars. In other words, Code First is not mapping your Children property because it doesn't know how to handle List.

One way to work around this is to define an entity type for the items in the list and use that instead. For example:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    // Your other code
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The shape of your Child class will likely be a bit different depending on exactly how it is used, which isn't clear from the question. I also added properties to act as keys since EF requires that each entity type has a key; again you may want to change this. Finally, I made the property virtual so that it will be lazily loaded when needed.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go that way finally. What do you think about serializing my `Children` list to a string that would be stored in the database? Would the addition of new item be difficult?

Answer (score 1):

You should do it in the constructor of your class, like this:

```
class Person {
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public List<string> Children { get; set; }
    public Person() {
        Children = new List<string>();
    }
    public Person(string first, string last, IEnumerable<string> children) {
        FirstName = first;
        LastName = last;
        Children = children.ToList();
    }
    ...
}
```

No matter how you construct `Person`, its `Children` member will not be `null`. You should call the second overload of the constructor in place of the `new Person{...}` syntax, this way you'd be able to make setters private (usually, it is a good thing to do).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought it was a good solution but didn't understand exactly what the difference would be. Unfortunately, this approach doesn't give better results for database seeding. I will continue to investigate...

Comment: @YannickBlondeau Could you be more specific about what's not working?

Comment: The result remains the same: even if the database seeding runs without any error, any subsequent query leads to a `Children` member being empty, as with the workaround I described at the end of the question.